# Your kernel headers for kernel 3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64 cannot be found

Tags: virtualbox, fedora

I am using Fedora 19 and have recently installed Virtual Box directly from the repositories of the Oracle Virtual Box. It was installed successfully but when I try to start a virtual machine it gives me following error:

`Failed to open a session for the virtual machine mint.
The virtual machine 'mint' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1.
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Machine
Interface: 
IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}`
 
`It then gives a dialog saying to execute`/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`command. When I execute this command at the terminal, it reports and error saying`Your kernel headers for kernel 3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64 cannot be found at
/lib/modules/3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64/build or /lib/modules/3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64/source. (Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules                      [FAILED]
  (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)`.

My `/var/log/vbox-install.log` reads as follow:

```
Uninstalling modules from DKMS
  removing old DKMS module vboxhost version  4.3.10

Deleting module version: 4.3.10
completely from the DKMS tree.

Done.
Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.3.10/source ->
                 /usr/src/vboxhost-4.3.10

DKMS: add completed.
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
Makefile:183: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
```

I googled a lot and found some solutions like installing following packages `yum install dkms binutils gcc make patch libgomp glibc-headers glibc-devel kernel-headers kernel-devel` but nothing is working for me. What is the problem? Please help me out of this problem.
I also exported KERN_DIR environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not running fedora, but had the same error. Un-installed using `apt-get purge virtualbox` Then reinstalled. Working fine now. Checked out this post -> [Error while installing virtualbox](https://superuser.com/questions/652850/error-while-installing-virtualbox) Fedora mentioned.